# How to iterate a JavaScript code for two objects

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to apply same piece of code to two objects in JavaScript.

When calling `getElementsByClass` ,there appears 2 objects in my website.So I would like to apply the same code for both of them.Currently I'm applying it to only one Object (**text[0]**) and I would like to implement it also to **text[1]** .

```
var text=document.getElementsByClassName("th");
var text =text[0];
        var newDom = '';
        var animationDelay = 6;

        for(let i = 0; i < text.innerText.length; i++)
        {
            newDom += '<span class="char">' + (text.innerText[i] == ' ' ? '&nbsp;' : text.innerText[i])+ '</span>';
        }

        text.innerHTML = newDom;
        var length = text.children.length;

        for(let i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            text.children[i].style['animation-delay'] = animationDelay * i + 'ms';
        }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you already know how to use `for` loops, so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @Jamiec No Bro,I'm a starter. This code was written by my Friend

Comment: @Ivar Nope I've already tried it

Comment: Try maybe to wrap the whole code in a for loop, where text = text[j]. I think this is more a lack of effort than a question.

Comment: [We've all got to start somewhere](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do the same thing with using `item[0]` and `item[1]` together.

You can create a function. Or call this function by iterating your items too.

```
var text=document.getElementsByClassName("th");


function myFunc(text) {
  var newDom = '';
        var animationDelay = 6;

        for(let i = 0; i < text.innerText.length; i++)
        {
            newDom += '<span class="char">' + (text.innerText[i] == ' ' ? '&nbsp;' : text.innerText[i])+ '</span>';
        }

        text.innerHTML = newDom;
        var length = text.children.length;

        for(let i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            text.children[i].style['animation-delay'] = animationDelay * i + 'ms';
        }
}
}

myFunc(text[0]); // call functions with your items.
myFunc(text[1]);
```